# Acumatica - Sales Order Allocation/Deallocation

Tags: acumatica

On Sales order the quantity is allocated by Allocation tab, Now due to some verification process we want to transfer this allocated Quantity to some different warehouse, How it can be transferred?

Note - after that verification this Lot/Ser will be transferred back to the Sales order for Shipment, but before that Shipment can not be done?

Main issue is in transferring the allocated quantities,

IN general everything is working ok and following are the results that does not allow the shipment -

1. ON SO allocation for warehouse ABC - INLorSerialStatus table has QtyAvail = 1 for ABC warehouse
2. On Verification transfer to other warehouse XYZ - INLorSerialStatus table has QtyAvail = -1 for ABC and QTYAvail for XYZ =1
3. On transferring back from verification to SO - QtyAvail =0 on ABC and QtyAvail =0 on XYZ
4. Shipment created issue as QtyAvail is 0.

Please do let me know why the step 2 Qtyavail is -1 i think it should be 0, and if it is expected behaviour what could be the issue.

Comment: What happens when you run Validate Inventory process?  Do the QtyAvail become positive?